# ReactJS component not re-rending after setState update?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I'm learning about ReactJS hooks and firebase, I'm getting users from the firestore and using the "Verify" button I set the user.status to "verified", This code works to verify the user in the firestore, however I don't know where exactly should I set the state
of the user in order to make the component re-render!

I would appreciate your help !

```
/* some imports have been hidden for making the code readable */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


import {db} from '../firebase'
import { collection, getDocs, query, where, updateDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore'



export default function Page() {

    const [error, setError] = useState("")
    const { currentUser, logout } = useAuth()
    const[status, setStatus] = useState("notverified")
    const history = useHistory()
    
    // firestore
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
    const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "users")
    const queryInverified = query(usersCollectionRef, where("status","==", "notverified"))



    const updateUser = async (id, status)=> {
      const userDoc = doc(db, "users", id)
      const newStatus = {status: status= "verified"}
      setStatus("verified")
      await updateDoc(userstDoc, newStatus)
      
     /* Following AKX 's answer! */
      setUsers((oldUsers) =>
      oldUsers.map((user) => 
      user.id === id? {...user, status} : user,
       ),
      );
    }
      
    }
    useEffect(() =>{


        const getUsers = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(queryInverified)
            setUsers(data.docs.map((doc)=>({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))}

        getUsers()      
    }, [])



    return (
        <>
        <Container>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>  
                    <div>
                       {users.map((user) => {
                           return(
                            <div className="card mb-4" >
                            <div className="card-body">
                              <h5>User Name: {user.name}</h5>
                              <p>Verification status: {user.status}</p>}                             
                              <Button onClick={() =>{updateUser(user.id, user.status)>
                              Verify</Button>
                              
                            </div>
                          </div>
                           )
                       })}

                    </div>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
       </Container> 
      </>
    ) 
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce this code a little, to be an [mcve] (e.g. remove all the code that isn't directly related to reproducing the problem like most of that JSX markup, history updating, etc), and then when you drop that in, make sure that it's indented properly? The clearer code is, the better folks can answer questions about it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're not updating the `users` state in any way after updating the user in Firebase.

You have about two options:

- an optimistic update of the local state, i. e. `setUsers(...)` after the updateDoc await to update the just-updated user in the users array:

  ```js
  setUsers((oldUsers) =>
    oldUsers.map((user) =>
      user.id === id ? { ...user, status } : user,
    ),
  );
  ```
- simply reload the data from Firebase afterwards; refactor that fetching code to another function you can call both in the current `useEffect` and within the updateUser handler.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'll use the 1st option but how can I pass in the updated-user only?

Comment: Sure! Added an example of that.

Comment: Thank you so so much! @AKX